# How to configure push notifications in independent apple watch application

Tags: ios, apple-push-notifications, apple-watch, watchos-6

We are developing independent apple watch application(Watch os 6) and we need to receive push notification.
So, how do we receive push notifications directly on watch?

Because of it is a independent app we don't have apple phone applications to support push notifications.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For independent watchOS apps you must register for remote push notifications by calling [`WKExtension.shared().registerForRemoteNotifications()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkextension/3141920-registerforremotenotifications?language=swift). Generally, you make this call in the [`applicationDidFinishLaunching()`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkextensiondelegate/1628241-applicationdidfinishlaunching?language=swift) delegate method implemented by your extension delegate. After calling to register for remote notifications, you should handle the success or failure by implementing [`didRegisterForRemoteNotifications(withDeviceToken:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkextensiondelegate/3141924-didregisterforremotenotification) and [`didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError(_:)`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/watchkit/wkextensiondelegate/3141923-didfailtoregisterforremotenotifi), respectively, in your extension delegate.

And regarding the presentation of a push notification (according to Apple's Developer documentation):

> To display alerts, play sounds, or perform other user-facing actions, you must also request authorization using the UNUserNotificationCenter class’s requestAuthorization(options:completionHandler:) method. If you do not request and receive authorization for your app’s interactions, the system delivers all remote notifications to your app silently.